# Comfortable way to use big and little endian at the same time?

Tags: c++, endianness

My compiler supports so-called "type qualifiers" `__bigendian` and `__littleendian`.
My variable `Buffer` looks like this:

```
static union
{
    uint8 as_byte[10];
    __bigendian uint16 as_big_endian[5];
    uint16 as_little_endian[5];
} Buffer;
```

In my case the microcontroller is little endian, however for some communication interface I need the 16bit units in big endian format.
The microcontroller supports an instruction `byte swap`, which is compiled in case those type qualifiers are used, so actually this seems to be a comfortable way to go.
The compiler manual says I should avoid using "type qualifiers" because of portability issues - of course!

I'm just wondering if there is a better way than using byte access and doing the swap manually depending on the endianess of the target?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  bear in mind for C++, accessing a variable in a union that was not last assigned is UB.

Comment: `union` won't swap bytes for you

Comment: @Anton Malyshev: Correct, but my idea was that using a simple assignment of the "little endian" element to the "big endian" element or vice versa is more efficient than using bitshifts because of that "byte swap" instruction.

Comment: if you code in C++, have a look in boost endian library.

Answer (score 6):

There are the more or less standard functions `ntohl` (32bits), `ntohs` (16bits) and their counterparts `htonl` and `htons`.

These functions convert from network to host endian and host to network endian respectively.

Network endian is always big endian.

Host endian depends on your target.

These functions are implemented usually with the instructions you comment (byte swap and the like), and using compiler preprocessor directives enable them or are just noop's.

Your compiler may already suppport them.

But for example, a typical implementation would look like:

```
#if TARGET_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    static inline uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t x) {
        //Do actual 32 bit swap
        return swap32(x);
    }
    static inline uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t x) {
        //Do actual 16 bit swap
        return swap16(x);
    }
#else
    #define ntohl(x) (x)
    #define ntohs(x) (x)
#endif

#define htonl(x) ntohs(x)
#define htons(x) ntohs(x)
```

Note that is only required to implement one pair of functions, since the other is just the same, only sintactic sugar.

Finally, you call these functions only in the actual receiving / transmitting functions. 
At any other part of your program you would work only in host endian.

Also, based on these functions, you can implement your custom `ntoh_structure` functions easily:

```
ntoh_struct(my_struct *st) {
    st->fieldA=ntohl(st->fieldA);
    st->fieldB=ntohl(st->fieldB);
}
#define hton_struct(st) ntoh_struct(st)
```

which, again, would only be used upon actual reception / transmission of data.

---

Note that the implementation of the functions `swapXX` is target and compiler dependant.

An implementation following your example (which I actually have not seen before), for `C` language would be as follows:

```
typedef union {
    __bigendian uint16_t be;
    uint16_t le;
} Buffer16;
typedef union {
    __bigendian uint32_t be;
    uint32_t le;
} Buffer32;

static inline uint16_t swap16(uint16_t x) {
    Buffer16 aux;
    aux.be=x;
    return aux.le;
}
static inline uint32_t swap32(uint32_t x) {
    Buffer32 aux;
    aux.be=x;
    return aux.le;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not to use a union at all, but to define the byte order of `uint8_t byte[10];`. If you decide to say that the byte order of this array is for example

```
[0]=MSB0 [1]=LSB0 [2]=MSB1 [3]=LSB1...
```

and CPU endianess be damned, you can then access it portably:

```
size_t index = i*2; // assuming i is 0 to 5
uint16_t word = (uint16_t)byte[index] << 8 | 
                (uint16_t)byte[index+1];
```

`word` does now contain MSB and LSB in the correct places, regardless of CPU endianess. The code is portable. The key here is to use bit shifts, they are superior to any other method (unions, pointer arithmetic etc).

As for sending this over a protocol with known big endianess, just grab the bytes in the expected order. In this case a simple `for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol buffer would solve endian issue but it has memory/processing overhead.
Please refer https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/